# Where's the rear view mirror?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In Grand Theft Auto V, how do you see out the back window of the car when driving in first person mode?

Whenever I try, all I can see is the inside of the car and a small portion of what's behind me. Camera height doesn't seem to make any difference either.

Comment: If you hold R3 it flips the camera backwards

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade! I've just removed the second question you had (about going into third person when shooting), as it's a separate question to this one. If you like, you can ask it separately. (Also, if you find the answer, let me know ;))

Comment: R3 doesn't give you the "rear view cam" anymore like it did in GTAIV. To see directly behind the car in GTAV, you have to switch to third person view and swivel the camera around manually.  If you use R3, it shows the cars front seat with only a small portion of the back window visible.  With trucks, you can't see behind you at all unless you do the above, or you're shooting.

Comment: I can only see the rear mirror when in 3rd person view, and even then, the mirror is pretty much useless, as it doesn't actually acts like a mirror, it only appears to do so.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rear view mirror. You can try using R3 to look behind you, but there is no actual functioning rear view mirror.